# Replacing a character string keeping case sensitivity

Tags: r, string, gsub

Basically i have 2 character vectors:

```
x='XYzD- xyZ      ABC'
y='xyz'
```

This is the best i could do.

```
gsub(paste0('[^ ',y,' $\\$]'), 'X', x, ignore.case = T)
```

Desired output is:

```
   'XXxXX xyZ      XXX'
```

which means that only the matching string i.e. y('abc') should be left as it else everything converted into letter 'X/x' depending on the capitalization.

taking a clear example:

```
x='XYzD- LMn      ABC'
y='lmn'

gsub(paste0('[^ ',y,' $\\$]'), 'X', x, ignore.case = T)
```

desired output in this case would be

```
'XXxXX LMn      XXX'
```

I hope this makes things clear.

Comment: Something is messed up. What output is expected for `'ABC abc XYZ xyz'`? Shoudn't your desired output be `'XXzXX xyX XXX'`?

Comment: @Marek you are right that's the desired o/p. BTW i mentioned Desired output is 'XXxXX xyZ XXX'.

Comment: what @Marek means is that the 'z' and 'Z' in your x should not be replaced according to your regex, e.g. 'XXzXX' vs 'XXxXX', 'xyZ' vs 'xyX'

Comment: It will be helpful if you explain in English what the rules of the replacement actually are. Posting failed code and then expecting us to read your intent is an extremely suboptimal procedure. You failed to get R to read your mind and now you expect us to do so? I don't think so.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee i  am trying to find a regex that will serve the purpose, z is irrelevant here, everything should be converted to 'X/x' except the matching string.

Comment: @42- I think u will find it clear now.

Comment: It only became somewhat more clear after I used the edit feature to see where you had spaces in the examples. Since you already have an answer you should correspond with @PLapointe.

Comment: @42- Yeah i kind of guessed it, poor formatting. I would take care of it in future. thanks anyway.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli I still don't get it. Why in your first example output isn't `'XYzXX xyZ      XXX' `? There are two occurrence of `'xyz'` pattern. Second: are you matching whole string (`'xyz'`) or any letter from it (so e.g. `'zAZBy`' will become `'zXZXy'`?

Comment: @Marek The output is what i could manage. see the desired output it doesnt have a z in it. Im trying to math the whole complete string.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli Please correct your question. At now it doesn't make sense. And answer you accepted is opposite to your comment - it matches letters not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a long solution. But it works. I'm using your second example. Basically, I transform everything to individual characters, find lower cases in the original and apply `tolower` to the result. I then concatenate everything back to a string.

```
x='XYzD- LMn      ABC'
y='lmn'

out <-gsub(paste0('[^ ',y,' $\\$]'), 'X', x, ignore.case = TRUE)

xx <-unlist(strsplit(x,"")) #split characters on original
out2 <-unlist(strsplit(out,"")) #split characters on result

lower <-grepl("[[:lower:]]",xx) #find lowercase
out2[lower] <-tolower(out2[lower]) #replace lowercase
paste(out2, collapse = "") #concatenate
#[1] "XXxXX LMn      XXX"
```

Comment: I was stuck at getting the regex in first place, but im sure i couldn't have thought of next steps also. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure regex solution using nested gsubs. The result of the first gsub on caps is followed by a second gsub to handle lowers..

```
gsub(paste0("[^", y, toupper(y), "A-Z", " ]"), 'x', 
        gsub( paste0("[^", y, toupper(y), "a-z", " ]"), 'X', x) )
[1] "XXxXX LMn      XXX"
```

It does depeond on the range operator in regex which is somewhat OS specific and the regex page has warnings about its use that you should read.